# Cant't see non-fatal errors in Firebase crashlytics with flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I'm using the last version of Crashlytics, but I cannot see the uncaught errors.

This is my main

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
  FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;

  runApp(BaseApp());
}
```

I'm doing all like described in the documentation:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage#handling-uncaught-errors

What am I missing? The forced crash test works perfectly.

These are the dependencies:

pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.2
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.1
```

In my app-level build.gradle I have this

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

and this in dependencies

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.1'
```

In my Android-level build.gradle, in dependencies:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
```

[EDIT]
Before you ask, I've already restarted the app several times, and the filter is on "non fatals"